# how to save JTextArea text?

Tags: java, save, jtextarea

I would like to know how to save JTextArea text that when user types something in area it stays there even when user exits the program and re-opens it.

Sorry for my bad english and grammar.

Comment: Use a database or save to a file and read from it.

Comment: You should read about [Data Persistence](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/What_is_Java_persistence%3F)

Comment: Also, posible duplicate of [Save JTextArea text to a txt file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980840/save-jtextarea-text-to-a-txt-file?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.

1. **Use a database:** You can store many different inputs in the database, and link it to the user who made the input, or anything else.
2. **Write to a .txt file:** This allows you to access the data from outside your application very easily.
3. **Serialize String:** You could save the text in a String and serialize the Object.

There are many ways to do it, hard to determine which is the best, as we do not know what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you probably want to use Swing components to expose fields in some "model" object, and save the model (to a database, file, etc.) only on explicit user action, but also save it to some user-private place on every user action ("auto-save").  However, [java.util.prefs.Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) may be useful for exactly what you're asking.  A simple example (untested):

```
public class SwingPrefsDemo extends JFrame {
  // other fields, etc...
  Preferences prefsNode = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(SwingPrefsDemo.class);
  JTextField tf_ta;

  public SwingPrefsDemo() {
    // ...
    tf_ta = new JTextArea();
    tf_ta.setText(prefsNode.get("tf_ta","enter text here"));
    this.add(tf_ta);
    tf_ta.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
      public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) { change(); }
      public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) { change(); }
      public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent evt) { change(); }
      private void change() {
        prefsNode.put("tf_ta",tf_ta.getText());
      }});
  } 
}
```

Comment: When i run your code or use your code and this:
JFrame j = new JFrame("");
j.setSize();
j.setVisible(true);

Code doesnt work. Is there something that i doing wrong ?